# How to compile c++11 in atom

Tags: c++, c++11, atom-editor

I've tried gpp-compiler but it uses c++98.
I would like to know if there is some way to compile c++11 within the atom app.
Thank you.

Comment: Check the atom documentation. This is not a programming related question.

Comment: @DavideSpataro Tools used by programmers also qualifies as a valid SO question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using Atom Script. Haven't tried it myself, but there is an issue on github ([see here](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/712)). Hopefully this will help you.